# SignalR messages process all at once when phone unlocks causing app to crash

Tags: c#, .net, angular, signalr

We have a web application with a .net backend and an angular front end. We use signalr to keep the client updated as backend data changes, currently using websockets. These updates are very frequent (around 1 a second).

On mobile, when we lock the phone we observe the following behavior:

1. The client continues to receive and process the signalr messages for a short while (~5 minutes).
2. The client stops processing the signalr messages
3. After unlocking the phone, all signalr messages that were sent since step 2 are bulk processed in one go causing terrible UX as the client freezes as it struggles to catch up with all the messages it missed.

These behavior seems to be common across all devices we have tested (iOS, Android)

How can this be handled? Is there a way to keep the client app alive while the phone is locked? I imagine this problem must be relatively common to mobile apps using signalr, but I cannot seem to find much information online about how it's handled.